# What determines if a "Street Pass" goes to your town?

Tags: bravely-default

So I just got my first 3DS and I'm kind of shaky on how it all works, so pardon my terminology. I want to get more workers for my town in Bravely-Default. I got something like 15 "passes" yesterday but no workers were added to my town. Then when I got to my friend's place, he was added to my town but my other friends weren't. I asked if he had ever played the game, or even the demo, and he hadn't even heard of it. Was he jerking my chain and lying to me,  or is there some other criteria that decides if a street pass gets added to my town?

Comment: If it works like other games, they need to have either the demo or the game on their system, and then they need to pass you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not currently playing Bravely Default (I played the demo, didn't really like it, and someone bought it for me but I haven't played the actual game yet), so there might be a better answer than mine from someone who actually knows what's going on in Bravely Default, but here's what I know. The [Streetpassing](http://www.streetpassing.com/3ds-games/bravely-default/) page might be helpful, even if I'm not.

When you have the option of saving you file in Bravely Default, you can update your data. (Also the bottom screen should have an update data button.) If someone has the game, but doesn't have Streetpass data set up, then you won't get them as a villager. It seems you have your Streetpass data set up, so... I mean, you should be fine on your end.

For 3DS games, the other people you pass [need to be playing the game](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/729328-bravely-default/68527249) (or have it transmitting) in order to get their streetpass data. However! Streetpass can be finicky. The issue is that [there's a cap on how many titles you can Streetpass on](http://www.reddit.com/r/3DS/comments/1vxvrw/today_i_learned_the_3ds_has_a_12_game_active/) and that might have something to do with how data is being transferred to your system. Say each of the people you passed have 12 games transferring data back and forth-- it's possible, then, that their data won't transfer to Bravely Default if Bravely Default isn't a part of the transmitting games. *Even if they check their games and say that Bravely Default is transmitting*. It's annoying, but you have to check in Settings > Data Management to know for sure.

On the off chance that the problem isn't that you're not getting villagers, but is that you aren't getting streetpass data from someone who you know has the game... Occasionally the Streetpass system doesn't catch that you've passed someone (my roommate has a 3DS and we sometimes don't "pass" each other, even if we both have the space/haven't passed each other in more than 8 hours. It's weird.) so you might have just had a situation where the system didn't catch you passing them. If you have proof of passing in the Mii Plaza, then I'd say it's the above problem or just that they never had the game or the demo.

If it's easier, imagine that when you pass someone else with a 3DS, your 3DS is sending out a message **"I am a 3DS, is there another 3DS out there?"** The other person who receives this message will return **"I am a 3DS, would you like to Streetpass?"** Your 3DS responds, **"Yes, I would like to Streetpass"**. Then your 3DS and the other 3DS do a compatibility check, i.e. they test the connection. But if any of these things fail-- like if your 3DS sends out **"I am a DS, is there another 3DS out there?"** and gets in return **"Yes, I would like to Streetpass"**-- then you don't get a connection. In other words, you need to have the conversation in one specific way and if it doesn't happen in that specific way, you don't get Streetpass data. This conversation is taking place in milliseconds and the possibility to mess up is there. In other words, if you and your friends are passing each other but not immediately getting streetpass data or you're not seeing their data at all, this could be why. (There's also a limit to how many times you can pass one person in a set amount of time.) In this case, the answer is to be patient.

Answer (score 1):

In order for streetpasses to contribute to Norede Village you need to "accept" the streetpasses through the inbox icon above the village icon (you'll notice something like "new" or "full" under it), then go to your village and your population will increase.

The demo and the full game can streetpass each other, as well as a portion of the demo's village being passed onto the full game if you choose to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You and other players need to meet the following conditions:

- Have *Bravely Default*
- Progressed far enough to enable StreetPass
- Have their 3DS Wi-Fi turned on
- And not have a full *BD* queue in StreetPass

Get within Wi-Fi range of each other and they will handshake, exchange StreetPass tickets and disconnect looking for more 3DSes to connect to.

I recomend you go to a [Nintendo Zone](http://www.nintendo.com/3ds/nintendozone), as that is an easy way of collecting many StreetPasses in one go.